# ASP.Net Async Blocking UI

Tags: asp.net, webforms, async-await, asp.net-ajax

I have a ASP.Net Web Forms application that calls a WCF service hosted on IIS via a button click event inside a Ajax Update panel.
When I click the button I call a WCF Async process that can take over 1 minute to return. I've noticed when the task is running and I open another tab in my browser the web page freezes/clocks until the long running task returns.  I assume that the first task is locking the UI thread causing anyone else to use the web page to have to wait.

How can I run a task, update the UI with the results and not block the UI for other Tabs/Users?

Here is a snipit of code:

```
 protected void btnsearch_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(async () =>
        {
            DataSet ds;
            ds = await data.GetReportAsync();

            grdsummary.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            grdsummary.DataBind();
        }));

    }
```

I did try adding .ConfigureAwait(false) to the Async call but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume that the first task is locking the UI thread causing anyone else to use the web page to have to wait.

This is ASP.NET; there's no UI thread.

Most likely, what is happening is that the [session state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) is preventing multiple simultaneous requests.

Note that multiple *users* will not be affected; only multiple requests in the *same session* will be seiralized.

Comment: I've tried this in IE and Firefox at the same time. If IE is running the report, then I go to Firefox and click on any link it just waits until IE has returned.

Comment: I having the same issue , I have a doubt can I cancel a current request , or is this possible in `TPL` that i can initiate a request on click can cancel that request if its takes long time ? I am trying this for long time, here is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324184/asp-net-while-first-request-processing-allow-second-request-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

Registering is one thing, Executing is one another :)

Just add an ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks call after and it should work fine, or please add the code where this call is done.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(async () =>
    {
        grdsummary.DataSource = await getSomeDataAsync();
        grdsummary.DataBind();
    }));
    Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
}
```

Comment: still seems to freeze until after the away is returned.  If I am awaiting on  grdsummary.DataSource = await getSomeDataAsync(); doesn't that mean Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks(); won't get fired until after the return?

Comment: I do see that the register code doesn't fire until prerender. I did add this code as suggested but still one page won't let another tab continue until the first query is completed.  I would of thought Async would not block the UI